# How to implement SAML in a Flutter Web Frontend Application and a SpringBoot REST API?

Tags: flutter, spring-boot, saml

I'm trying to implement SAML into my application, which consists of a SPA (Flutter Web) and a REST API (Springboot). But I have a problem with implementing the communication between the Flutter Frontend application, the Springboot Rest API and the SAML Identity Provider.

Currently I have implemented an initial HTTP Request (@GetMapping("/initial")), which is called  when the Flutter application is launched, which checks if SAML is configured and then sends the Authentication Post Request to the Identity Provider.
My problem is that the Identity Provider answers to the Rest API to another Post Mapping in the RestController (@PostMapping("samlsso").
Then I generate a Bearer Token for the authenticated user to pass to the Flutter application to handle the Authentication status in the application and automatically log the user in.

But how do I get this token to the Flutter application? Since I'm using a REST controller I shouldn't save any variables in the controller, but in order for the Flutter application to receive data from the Rest API, it has to send a request for the token itself. But the Flutter application does not know, when the token is ready to receive. How can I implement this communication properly whitout any manual delays and saving values in variables in a RestController class?

PS: I have already tried sending a response.redirect from the PostMapping, which receives and handels the SAML response, directly to the Frontend, but I was only able to send it via the header and was not able to access it from the Flutter application.

Backend Code:

```
@RestController
class SamlController {

    var samlToken = ""

    @GetMapping("/initial")
    fun findToken() {
        sendAuthRequestToIdp()
    }

    @PostMapping("/samlsso")
    fun findAll(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse) {
        val user = receiveAndHandleIDPResponse()
        //handle errors

        val token = generateTokenFromIDPResponse()
    
        samlToken = token
    }

    @PostMapping("/getSamlToken")
    fun findAll(): ResponseEntity<String> {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(samlToken)
    }
}
```

Frontend Code:

```
Future<String> fetchSamlAuthentication () async {
  var jwtString = '';

  await launch("api_url/initial"); // launch, so that the IDP website opens in the browser
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10000));//wait manually until token has been generated
  final response = await _client.post(Uri.parse("api_url/getSamlToken"), headers: headers);
  jwtString = response.body;

  return jwtString;
}
```

This is the only way I was able to authenticate a user with SAML, but it is not a clean/useable solution. I need a better way to get the genreated token to the Flutter application and be able to handle it.

Comment: Have you been able to get it working in the meanwhile? 

If not: your ACS endpoint (/samlsso) needs to return a success response to the identity provider. Then the provider will forward the original HTTP that the browser sent to /initial back to your Flutter front-end. The ACS endpoint should also set an authentication cookie for the frontend. The cookie is how you log the frontend in.

Answer (score 2):

SAML 2.0 is browser-based; after the IdP has authenticated the user, the IdP sends a SAML response *via the browser* to the app's backend. This is likely the call to `POST /samlsso` in your question.

The app's backend should then validate the SAML response, such as checking that any signatures contained in the SAML response are valid given the IdP's SAML metadata that will have been previously obtained when the SAML connection was set up.

Once validated, the app's backend should complete the `POST /samlsso` by sending a redirect response that includes a token or cookie that indicates that the user has been authenticated. How this is done will depend on your frontend, particularly whether it is browser-based or not.

In your case, as your app's frontend is running in the browser and you want to use a bearer token for subsequent requests (versus say a session cookie), then you can include the token in the URL that you redirect to, which should be a route within your Flutter app.

When your Flutter app then reloads it can retrieve the token from the URL and pass it on subsequent API calls via each request's Authorization header.
Hopefully, your bearer token will have been signed by your backend when it was created so that the backend can verify that it was legitimately obtained when serving subsequent requests.